# ASP.NET Website: page with multiple forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, runat

I'm having a problem while creating dynamically a web page in ASP.NET (C#).

I need to insert multiple form tags in that page, I know that I can't put
more than one with **runat="server"** attribute and I don't need it.

I want to place them from C# (one for each element I've got to manage), without the **runat** attribute but the **HtmlForm** object
that I use for insert the form adds the runat attribute automatically and I can't remove it
(tried with *form.Attributes.Remove("runat")*)

If I use a simple string like:

```
"<form id="someID" method="POST" action=""></form>"
```

and I add it multiple times into my div it works.
The point is that I don't want to insert ALL my HTML objects writing them in a string
and add it with *InnerHTML* method. I'm looking for an object that manage a Form without
the runat attribute or a way to remove that from **HtmlForm**.

Comment: You might use javascript.

Comment: Are you using web forms? with web forms you can only have one form per page!

Comment: I'm not using Web Forms. Like a said, if I use InnerHTML property to insert forms it works.
@cullub I would prefer to not use JavaScript. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Are you using Microsoft Visual Studio?  If so, what version?

Comment: Yes, VS Express 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user control is probably the cleanest solution but you can add an `HtmlGenericControl` instead of a `HtmlForm` object which isn't bound to any specific attributes.

```
Dim ctrl As New HtmlGenericControl("form")
ctrl.Attributes.Add("id", "someID")
ctrl.Attributes.Add("method", "POST")
ctrl.Attributes.Add("action", "")
OuterDivContainer.Controls.Add(ctrl)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add controls dynamically to a page and make the web page render them as pure html, instead of rendering asp:Controls you can use the Literal control. Check this [link](http://ganeshmohan.wordpress.com/aspnet-and-c-generate-html-controls-dynamically/) or [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1(v=vs.90).aspx)